# How can I use pinpoint mobile sdk to submit events from my angular web app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

How can I use aws pinpoint mobile sdk to submit events from my web app. So that I can analyse user activity and send push notifications to web app also using FCM. For Android I could see sdk and samples.

If possible, where can I find sample web script and sdk to leverage activity based user reengage using push notification across platform.(Android and Angular4)

Thanks,
Venugopal.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question. For submitting events to Pinpoint outside of a mobile device, you can use the Mobile Analytics SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-mobile-analytics-js. This link also has an usage example. Assuming you have registered an Endpoint, events that flow through the Mobile Analytics SDK will reach Pinpoint.

Thank you,
Grahem